# Access MSI error table

Tags: wix

How to access the MSI error table from a custom  action DLL so that the custom messages can be added to the error table?

Comment: Unmanged C++ DLL or Managed C#/VB.NET dll?  What is your use case that requires the error messages to be added at Install time rather then build time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MsiCreateRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370072%28VS.85%29.aspx). The first record field must contain the error id in Error table.

```
UINT __stdcall ShowErrorMessage(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
  //Load the error and format it    
  PMSIHANDLE hError = MsiCreateRecord(2);
  MsiRecordSetInteger(hError, 1, <error_id>);
  MsiRecordSetString(hError, 2, <parameter_to_format>);


  //Display the message
  MsiProcessMessage(hInstall,INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR,hError);
  return ERROR_SUCCESS; 
}
```